# How to use moment in jest react unit test?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, jestjs

I have a Unit component that uses moment.js to set the format for a date:

```
let bdate= moment(this.props.person.birthDate).format(
                'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
              );
```

Later this bdate gets rendered in the component.

This component has a unit test:

```
describe('Unit', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const person = 
      {      
        birthDate: '2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z',
      }

    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Unit
        person={person}
      />
    );
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The issue is that the snapshot for Unit outputs the current date? Why not the mockdate? How can I fix this so the snaphot stays the same ?

Comment: Can you share the code for `Unit`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [mockdate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate) util for that. It allows you to mock "now" value for the test.